Tensor identity in L&L book 2
How does the identity
$$\epsilon^{prst}A_{ip}A_{kr}A_{ls}A_{mt}=-A\epsilon_{iklm}$$
with the Levi Civita symbol $\epsilon$ and the determinant A of the matrix $A_{ik}$ follow from the equation
$$\epsilon^{iklm}\epsilon_{prst}=-\begin{vmatrix} \delta^i_p & \delta^i_r & \delta^i_s & \delta^i_t \\ \delta^k_p & \delta^k_r & \delta^k_s & \delta^k_t \\ \delta^l_p & \delta^l_r & \delta^l_s & \delta^l_t \\ \delta^m_p & \delta^m_r & \delta^m_s & \delta^m_t \\ \end{vmatrix}$$
where the $\delta$ are Kronecker deltas and the vertical lines represent the determinant?
(i found it in §6 of L&L book 2 where it says that the first equation follows directly from the second and cannot really see how to draw the connection)

Perhaps this can be of help?

what happened to $j$? Also, who know NIST was keeping standards on isotropic tensors up to rank-8? The section on Capelli's Identity may address your question: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/79b/jresv79bn1-2p49_a1b.pdf ...wait, never mind, you're in 4-D. NIST is 3...are we still Euclidean, since you're using latin super/super scripts? Note also: NIST skips "l" because it looks like "1", but it keeps "j" around.

It's literally just the Leibniz formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants

Hmm, I wouldn't think too hard about the second identity. The first identity is almost self evident from the fact that $\det A = \epsilon^{ijkl} A_{0i}A_{1j}A_{2k}A_{3l}$ and the antisymmetry of the determinant when changing rows (you just have to take care of the sign-convention).

These trivialities were developed simply by checking both sides for simple entries from $0,1$. The full n dimensional LeviCivita symbol is the coefficient tensor of the n-dimensional signed volume element, normal notation today $d^4x = dx_1\wedge \dots dx_4$ as a multilinear antisymmetric function of 4 variables.
Since the four indices $i,k,l,m$ in the result are fixed, one can simply contract the LeviCivita tensor with four vectors differently  named vectors
$$\text{tc}=\sum_{(i_1,i_5),(i_2,i_6),(i_3,i_7),(i_4,i_8)}\left(\epsilon  ^{(4)}   
\otimes \vec a \otimes \vec b \otimes \vec c \otimes \vec d \right)  $$
e.g. explicitely in Mathematica
   tc = TensorContract[ 
   TensorProduct[LeviCivitaTensor[4], 
   (Subscript[a, #] &) /@ Range[4], 
   Subscript[b, #] & /@ Range[4], 
   Subscript[c, #] & /@ Range[4], 
   Subscript[d, #] & /@ Range[4]] , 
   {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 8}}]  

$$a_4 b_3 c_2 d_1-a_3 b_4 c_2 d_1-a_4 b_2 c_3 d_1+a_2 b_4 c_3 d_1+a_3 b_2 c_4 d_1-a_2 b_3 c_4 d_1$$ $$-a_4 b_3 c_1 d_2+a_3 b_4 c_1 d_2+a_4 b_1 c_3 d_2-a_1 b_4 c_3 d_2-a_3 b_1 c_4 d_2+a_1 b_3 c_4 d_2$$
$$+a_4 b_2 c_1 d_3-a_2 b_4 c_1 d_3-a_4 b_1 c_2 d_3+a_1 b_4 c_2 d_3+a_2 b_1 c_4 d_3-a_1 b_2 c_4 d_3$$ $$-a_3 b_2 c_1 d_4+a_2 b_3 c_1 d_4+a_3 b_1 c_2 d_4-a_1 b_3 c_2 d_4-a_2 b_1 c_3 d_4+a_1 b_2 c_3 d_4$$
This is apparently equal to the determinant of the four vectors, that is the alternating sum of the diagonal product $a_1 b_2 c_3 d_4$ over all $4!$ permutations.
The negative sign is the effect of lowering or lifting  all four indices with negative signature of the Lorentz metric
